# Implementing large interface

Tags: typescript, interface, implementation

I am using a library that has a large interface

```
interface IOrder{
    cutomerId: number;
    deliveryAddress1: string;
   // and lots of properties...
}
```

And I want to implement a class extending it.

Just want to confirm that it is necessary to re-declare all the properties.

```
class Order implements IOrder{
        cutomerId: number;

       /*  error: Class 'Order' incorrectly implements interface 'IOrder'.
             Property 'deliveryAddress1' is missing in type 'Order'
       */
}
```

Of course, methods need to be implemented but I find re-declaring the properties redundant. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably you are missing some kind of an abstract class. Anyway such big interfaces are against [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). This indicates poor abstraction as well, meaning probably [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to redeclare all the fields if you implement the interface. You can do a workaround by creating a function that creates a class that implements the interface. The implementation will not actually add any code or fields it will just declare that it does so if the interface contains only fields it works although the fields will remain uninitialized, but if it has methods they will be undefine:

```
function autoExtend<T>(): new () => T {
    return class {} as any
}

class Order extends autoExtend<IOrder>() {

}

var cc = new Order();

cc.cutomerId = 0;
```

In typescript 2.8 you could also define `autoExtend` to remove methods, to avoid potential errors for interfaces with methods:

```
type NonMethodKeys<T> = ({[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : P } & { [x: string]: never })[keyof T];  
type RemoveMethods<T> = Pick<T, NonMethodKeys<T>>; 

function autoExtend<T>(): new () => RemoveMethods< T> {
    return class {} as any
}

class Order extends autoExtend<IOrder>() implements IOrder {
    // Must define method
    method(){

    }
}
```

Comment: hats off to your elegant solutions

Comment: @Joan 10x, also added a 2.8 version taht removed methods from an interface for extra safety :)

Comment: Refinement! I have yet to install 2.8 but the simpler first worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

You need re-declare all the properties. Because the interface binds the properties of the implementation class

```
class Order implements IOrder{
    cutomerId: number;
    deliveryAddress1: string;
    /*all properties of interface ...*/
```

}