# Create class from interface without redundancy

Tags: typescript

I am looking to take an interface and create a *thin* class wrapper for that interface without all the duplication of properties in the constructor and in the class.

```
interface _Notes {
  date: Date;
}

class Notes implements _Notes{
  date: Date;
  constructor (n: _Notes) {
    this.date = n.date;
  }
}
```

What I want is something simpler like this:

```
class Notes implements _Notes{
  constructor (n: _Notes) {
    Object.assign(this, n)
  }
}
```

or simply:

```
class Notes implements _Notes {}
```

Comment: I think this is basically the same question as this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189557/implementing-large-interface/49189666#49189666 Agreed ?

Comment: redundancy is a good thing as it allows typescript to check consistency in interface and class, right?

Answer (score 1):

For non-generic interface, you can create reusable function that creates a class and calls `Object.assign()` in the constructor

```
export interface PropertiesConstructor<Properties> {
    new(p: Properties): Properties;
}

export function Implementation<Properties>(): PropertiesConstructor<Properties> {
    return class {
        constructor(p: Properties) {
            Object.assign(this, p);
        }
    } as PropertiesConstructor<Properties>
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
interface _Notes {
  date: Date;
}

class Notes extends Implementation<_Notes>() {
    constructor(n: _Notes) {
        super(n);
    }
}
```

You still have to declare a constructor and don't forget to pass constructor argument to `super()`, so it does not eliminate the redundancy completely, but I think it's useful.

But if your interface is generic, there's a problem:

```
interface _Data<ItemType> {
  item: ItemType;
}

class Data<ItemType> extends Implementation<_Data<ItemType>>() {

// error: Base class expressions cannot reference class type parameters.
```

To avoid this error, you can pass `any` as type parameter for the interface, and redeclare all properties which depend on type parameter in the class:

```
interface _Data<ItemType> {
    item: ItemType;
    timestamp: Date;
}

class Data<ItemType> extends Implementation<_Data<any>>() {

    item: ItemType;

    constructor(n: _Data<ItemType>) {
        super(n);
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }
}
```

Again, not much better than the Titian's answer for [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189557/implementing-large-interface/49189666#49189666), but still you did not have to redeclare `timestamp` in this example.